# jQuery - how to write a custom queue?

Tags: jquery, queue

i'm trying to make a custom queue,
could you tell me what i'm doing wrong?

here is a the code in action:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1292831/hell/index2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    .tester {
        background:red;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        left: 900px;
        top: 300px;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .counter {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 150px;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){

            // animation for the 'FX' queue:
        $('.tester').fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000) 


            // animation for the 'lolo' queue:
        $('.tester').queue('lolo',function(next){
            $(this).animate({left: 100}, {duration:1000})
            next()
            })

    $('.tester').queue('lolo',function(next){
            $(this).animate({left: 800}, {duration:1000})
            next()
            })
            .dequeue('lolo')
    })


    // counters
    setInterval(function(){
        var count = $('.tester').queue('fx').length
        $('.counter #c1').html(count)

        var count = $('.tester').queue('lolo').length
        $('.counter #c2').html(count)

    }, 250)

</script>


</head>
<body>

<p class="counter">
    items in the 'fx' queue <span id="c1"></span> <br />
    items in the 'lolo' queue <span id="c2"></span>
</p>

<div class="tester"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**  As of jQuery 1.7, `animate` does take an option to specify a custom queue to add the animation to.

---

It's not entirely clear what the issue here is, but I think from looking at the example, you're expecting the animations within the queue to be on a different queue.

Here's the problem.  Animate always goes on the fx queue.  I'm not aware of any way to put it on another queue.  So, the reason you're always seeing 0 on your custom queue is that the things you are queueing on it finish immediately.  They simply call animate (putting the animation on the fx queue) and finish.  This is also why you are seeing 4 initially on the fx queue.

One way around this, is to run the animations in your custom queue with `queue:false`, but then handle the delays yourself in that queue.  For example:

http://jsfiddle.net/jRawX/6/

```
    $(function(){

        // animation for the 'FX' queue:
    $('.tester').fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000) 


        // animation for the 'lolo' queue:
    $('.tester')
        .queue('lolo',function(next){
            $(this).animate({left: 100}, {duration:1000, queue:false, complete: next})
        })
        .queue('lolo',function(next){
            $(this).animate({left: 600}, {duration:1000, queue:false, complete: next})
        })
        .dequeue('lolo')
})


// counters
setInterval(function(){
    var count = $('.tester').queue('fx').length
    $('.counter #c1').html(count)

    var count = $('.tester').queue('lolo').length
    $('.counter #c2').html(count)

}, 250)
```

There may be a better way to do this, I just made this one up.  But I was unable to find any way to animate on a different queue.

EDIT: Improved slightly, calling next on the animate callback.

Comment: thank, it works like a charm! for my current project it more then enough. 

still, hope to find a way to do somthing like .animate('lolo', {left: 100}, 1000)...